# Exception has occurred. _CastError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' in type cast)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dictionary

When I try to run the app an animation stops circling around and doesn't move anywhere then I press 'Stepover' the animation starts endlessly circling around and drops another error. Not quite sure how to fix it.

categoryservice.dart

```
    DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await categories.doc('categories').get();
    var data = snapshot.data() as Map;
    var categoriesData = data['categories'] as List<dynamic>;
    categoriesData.forEach(
      (catData) {
        Category cat = Category.fromJson(catData);
        _categories.add(cat);
      },
    );
  }
```

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRVjT.jpg)

When stepping over.

```
 CategoryService.getCategoriesCollectionFromFirebase (package:foodshare/services/categoryservice.dart:21:32) <asynchronous suspension>

Running "flutter pub get" in foodshare...
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                           784.0s
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:58491/GgqClrs0f1A=/ws
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' in type cast
#0      CategoryService.getCategoriesCollectionFromFirebase (package:foodshare/services/categoryservice.dart:21:32)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kAgR.jpg)

[Code on Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/sbxUP5wV)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DocumentSnapshot snapshot` has the type of `Map<String, dynamic>`. Try to write your code like this:

```
 DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await categories.doc('categories').get();
  if(snapshot.exists){
    Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
        var categoriesData = data['categories'] as List<dynamic>;
        categoriesData.forEach(
          (catData) {
            Category cat = Category.fromJson(catData);
            _categories.add(cat);
          },
        );
  }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, mate. Still the same error :)


```[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast
#0      CategoryService.getCategoriesCollectionFromFirebase (package:foodshare/services/categoryservice.dart:21:49)
<asynchronous suspension>
Restarted application in 528ms.```

Comment: You should also check if `snapshot.data()` is `null` or not. I removed that from the code to focus on the type issue. Just updated the answer. Pls try it with the updated snipped. We can check if the documentSnapshot exists or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate. Your approach has helped me to overcome the issue :)